# Magento addColumn() to add a "View" link at end of each product record

Tags: magento

I want to add a link to product display page at the end of each product record in the product list at Catalog -> Manage Products.

Thus far I found I should edit Grid.php and came up with the follow code:

```
$this->addColumn('view',
            array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('View'),
                'width'     => '50px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'     => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('View'),
                        'url'     => array(
                            'base'=>'*/*/view',
                            'params'=>array()
                        ),
                        'field'   => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
        ));
```

Now I'm at a loss how to get the product page URL of the current product (row).

Any idea how I can change the above code to get what I want? Simply a link to the product page of the current product row.... Just like that of a wordpress post that has a View Post link to open up the frontend post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got this myself. See detailed instructions here:

http://magentogoreview.lisabuy.com/add-view-product-page-link-to-products-list-at-catalog-manage-products~280